# django cms tries to import unrelated project

Tags: django-cms

Following this tutorial on windows: https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Initial%20Setup.md

typing this line:

```
djangocms -p . my_site
```

I have this error:

```
OSError: Could not import settings 'ira_site.settings' 
(Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): 
No module named 'ira_site'
```

1. ira_site is the name of an unrelated django (no-cms) project.
2. I've grepped (using ransack) the whole "c:\python34" and "virtual_env" folders to look for "ira_site". Not a trace of it.
3. I've opened every settings.py file I could open. To check of installed apps.

Not trace of it. Why would djangocms installer try to import the settings of a totally unrelated django project ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, it was quite stupid. In case someone has the same problem:

your environment variables:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Must be set so django-admin.py can find it ( as the installer is also creating the project ). What I did is:

1. reset it to global-settings.py
2. run the installer.
3. And once installation was over, put it back to the settings.py file of the newly created site.